# Spark SQL query returns output although hive table does not contain enough records on queried column

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I got output from spark SQL query despite the fact that the actual hive table doesn't contain enough records on queried column. The hive table is partitioned by integer column **date_nbr** which contains values like **20181125**, **20181005** for some reason I had to truncate the table (**Note: I did not delete the partitions directory in HDFS**) and reload the table for the week **date_nbr=20181202**

After data load I run below query on hive and got expected result

`SELECT DISTINCT date_nbr FROM transdb.temp
date_nbr
20181202`

but spark SQL doesn't give the same output as hive

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT DISTINCT date_nbr FROM transdb.temp").map(_.getAs[Int](0)).collect.toList
res9: List[Int] = List(20181125, 20181005, 20181202)
```

I'm bit confused by the spark sql result.

Comment: did you run `spark.catalog.refreshTable("transdb.temp")`?

Comment: Yeah I did, but got the same result